# Web scrapping Dermnet Images

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

trying to web scrape images from [text](https://dermnetnz.org/search.html?q=basal+cell+carcinoma+dermoscopy) but can't access the div block using Beutiful soup any solutions ?

I also tried usng selenium but its still not working.The website is using sava script to dynamically load images and I think thats an issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you open developer console on this site you can see that it uses google search api to list image (cse.google.com)

So to get list of images just look at Network tab in dev console and you will see  https://cse.google.com/cse/element/v1?rsz=large&num=16&hl=en&source=gcsc&gss=.com&cselibv=8e77c7877b8339e2&searchtype=image&cx=015036873904746004277:nz7deehiccq&q=basal%20cell%20carcinoma%20dermoscopy&safe=off&cse_tok=AFW0emwRaupmNcwPmPDnZm7vKaJV:1684998350721&exp=csqr,cc,bf&callback=google.search.cse.api10440

which return json object with "results" but it is paginated so observe network tab how parameters change according to current page of results.